# I want to create 2 dimension array using new Array and fill in javascript but the result does not behave like array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to create a 2 dimension array using this code

```
const fieldBloom = new Array(this.height).fill(new Array(this.width).fill("✼"));
```

but when i tried to mutate it with fieldBloom[0][0] = "A" it change all of the first element in the 2 dimension array

```
[
  [ 'A', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼' ],
  [ 'A', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼' ],
  [ 'A', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼' ],
  [ 'A', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼' ],
  [ 'A', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼', '✼' ]
]
```

What is going on here? what can I change to make it behave like an array ( only change the value to "A" at index [0][0] )

I run the code using node.js v18.12.1

Comment: ["Value to fill the array with. Note all elements in the array will be this exact value: __if value is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object__."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#parameters)

Comment: thanks andy, i got it using this way. but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

const fieldBloom = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
      let temp = new Array(this.width).fill("✼");
      fieldBloom.push(temp);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that all of the values change is a clue that Array.fill() creates references to the object.  This is a shallow copy.  To get your desired behavior you need to make a new array in every slot of the outer array.  You could use a loop, or a helper method like map.

```
const fieldBloom = Array(this.height).fill(null).map(_ => Array(this.width).fill('*'))
```